# Chrome deleteUrl() doesn't actually delete anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to build a chrome extension and would like to have the ability to delete certain websites from my history. As an example I am trying to delete all references to YouTube from my browsing history. The extension doesn't throw any errors or warnings in the popup console. The problem is that after the items are "deleted" they still show up in my history.

Anyways here is the code

Manifest File

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Eraser",
"description": "This extension will delete history",
"version": "1.0",

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
 "history",
 "browsingData"
],
"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html",
 "default_title": "Erase"
}
```

Javascript

```
function erase(){
var now = new Date();
var milleSecondsInAYear = 31536000000;
var oneYearAgo = now.getTime() - milleSecondsInAYear;
chrome.history.search({"text":"Youtube", "startTime":oneYearAgo, "maxResults":1000000},
function(history){
    for(var i = 0; i < history.length; i++){
        chrome.history.deleteUrl({"url":history[i].url});
    }
    $("#result").html( $("#result").html() + history.length + " items have been removed");
});
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I did. No errors in the console and execution makes it to the delete function. The search function is also functioning properly and passing all instances of Youtube in the "history" variable.

Comment: The result also properly shows the amount of items passed within the history variable. The first time I ran it, it deleted 10 items, running it again without creating any new history will delete 0 items. Looking in the history screen I can still see the 10 deleted items. If I navigate to youtube again and the run the extension, it will say 1 item deleted.

Comment: I just manually deleted the Cache, Downloads and Cookies then restarted the browser. The 10 youtube items were still there when opened it again. They didn't have the little red youtube icon anymore though, but that's not the point.

Comment: Sounds like a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=chrome.history.deleteUrl) then.

Comment: In fact it was this bug thank you, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955

Answer (score 1):

If you have history sync enabled, then the deleteURL will not remove anything from the chrome://history list. Updating the Advanced sync settings to the following did the trick for me.

[image]